# What is the syntax for evaluating string matches on regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, string

How do I determine if a string matches a regular expression?

I want to find True if a string matches a regular expression.

Regular expression:

```
r".*apps\.facebook\.com.*"
```

I tried:

```
if string == r".*apps\.facebook\.com.*":
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What tutorial are you reading?  Have you looked at the Python library documentation for `re`?  http://docs.python.org/library/re.html  This seems pretty clear.  What part **specifically** is confusing you?

Comment: You seem confused by what prefixing a string with "r" accomplishes.  It does not make the string a regular expression, it just automatically escapes any "\" in the string (which is useful when writing regular expressions).  See http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Python docs: [on re module, regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

```
import re  
if re.search(r'.*apps\.facebook\.com.*', stringName):
    print('Yay, it matches!')
```

Since re.search returns a MatchObject if it finds it, or None if it is not found.

Answer (score 2):

You have to import the `re` module and test it that way:

```
import re

if re.match(r'.*apps\.facebook\.com.*', string):
    # it matches!
```

You can use `re.search` instead of `re.match` if you want to search for the pattern anywhere in the string. `re.match` will only match if the pattern can be located at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

match = re.search(r'.*apps\.facebook\.com.*', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `re.match()`:

```
import re

if (re.match(r'.*apps\.facebook\.com.*', string)):
    do_something()
```

Or, if you want to match the pattern anywhere in the string, use `re.search()`.

Why don't you also read through the Python documentation for the [re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)?